# How to get a number closest to the average in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

What I'm trying to achieve is to take the average of the numbers stored in the array and find the number which is closest to it.
My code compiles, but has an error just after starting. I think it's something to do with the memory handling (I don't feel confident with pointers, etc. yet)
Could some nice guy take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong with it? (don't be hard on me, I'm a beginner)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average);

int main()
{
    double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    double average = 0;
    double* p = aver(arr,size,average);
    cout << *p << " " << average << endl;
}

double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average){
    int i,j,sum;
    double* m = 0;
    int tmp[7];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    average = sum/size;
    for(j=0;j<size;j++){
        tmp[j] = arr[j] - average;
        if(abs(tmp[j])>*m)
        *m = tmp[j];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Don't use pointers. Seriously, you got to stop using pointers.

Comment: "Number closest to the average"? Do you just mean you want the average?

Comment: "An error" -- which one? *Always* add this information. Preferrably, also an actual input list and outout, and expected output.

Comment: this code is not `C++`, but plain old `C` with some extensions (reference).

Comment: @Walter: No, it is certainly C++.  It would not compile as C.  The use of procedural programming rather than OOP does not make it "not C++".  C++ supports both paradigms.

Comment: @Clifford, I'm pretty sure he refers to the fact that he is using C-style arrays?

Comment: @Jefffrey: .. which are valid C++.  I don't see your point.

Comment: @Clifford, of course they are. Why use them though, when there's something much better?

Comment: @Jefffrey: Several possibilities; most likely is that the Alex is perhaps learning programming from scratch and you cannot learn the whole language in one go.  Some might choose to teach/learn STL containers *before* arrays, but most material starts with arrays.  Another possibility (one which applies to most code I write) is that the code targets a resource constrained or real-time embedded systems where either the memory footprint or the potentially non-deterministic behaviour of dynamically allocated containers is prohibitive. The "this is not C++" comment was inaccurate and unnecessary.

Comment: [Koenig/Moo's Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example](http://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X) is an example of a teaching approach that starts with higher level C++ constructs rather than the more common and perhaps misguided *C subset first* approach.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Elsewhere it is apparent that this is a school assignment.  Keeping within the subset of taught material is more pragmatic than "being clever" if you want to get the marks.  A hard pressed and possibly inexpert tutor, may not be equipped to fairly award marks to code outside the course material and thus the marking scheme.

Comment: @Clifford, "Elsewhere it is apparent that this is a school assignment" -- The OP never mention it and there's not a single hint in the text that suggests the OP is learning in school. If it is normal for you to *assume* things like that just because the OP says "I'm a beginner", then maybe we are living in two very different universes. "The "this is not C++" comment was inaccurate and unnecessary" -- True, and I haven't posted it. My point was that behind that comment there was some truth: starting from C-style arrays in C++ is not learning C++, but learning the C subset it contains.

Comment: Oh, and if you are going to show me [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608098/how-to-get-a-number-closest-to-the-average-in-c?noredirect=1#comment29106476_19608116), you might just as well hold on since it was posted ~1 hour later than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608098/how-to-get-a-number-closest-to-the-average-in-c?noredirect=1#comment29105920_19608098).

Comment: @Jeffrey:  Yes, I appreciate it became explicit that it was a school assignment *after* the event - but looking at the nature of the problem, that is perhaps apparent in any case.  The question could be improved in that sense to get a more appropriately levelled answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following

```
double* m = 0;
```

sets `m` to the null pointer. Any attempt to dereference it will result in undefined behaviour.

Change the above to:

```
double m = 0;
```

and replace `*m` with `m` everywhere, also changing the function's return type to just `double`.

Finally, you don't need the `tmp` array.

Comment: Do you exclusively answer questions that concern null pointer abuse?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't, but perhaps I should. :)

Comment: yeah, but the thing is it's a school assignment and the return type has to be double* :( that's why I use the pointers

Comment: @AlexZielinski: Well, don't change the return type then. Think how you can return a pointer (it's not hard, but I'll leave it to you to figure out).

Comment: @AlexZielinski:  You need to return a pointer to a member of the passed `arr` rather than a local variable which will be out of scope after the function returns.  Using your method, that would be `return &arr[j] ;`

Comment: @AlexZielinski: Note that eradicating the `tmp` array without modifying `arr` requires a different (somewhat smarter) algorithm, and returning `&arr[j]` as I suggested requires that `arr[]` is unmodified.  So while you don't *need* `tmp` you might keep it unless you can come up with a better algorithm - that might warrant posting a new question if you want to explore that.

Answer (score 2):

1 *What's wrong with your code?* The use of pointers and the resulting beginner errors.

2 *How to compute the average in C++?* Roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
  auto average = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),0.0) / arr.size();
  std::cout  << " average = " << std::setprecision(16) << average << std::endl;
}
```

(note: compile with option `-std=c++11`)

3 *How to find the number closest to it (the average)?* If your computer is IEEE compliant (most are but some compiler optimisations violate that), the result of any arithmetic is rounded to the closest representable number. So, nothing special needs to be done here. However, accumulation of numbers is subject to round-off error and hence loss of precision. This can be minimised by accumulating the numbers in descending order of their absolute value, though there exist pathological cases where the computed accumulation is still rather imprecise. Find out more on, say, wikipedia.

4 *How to find the **array value** closest to it (the average)?* One way is shown in Johan's answer. However, it unnecessarily alters the array by performing a partial sort. Better use `std::min_element`
(no need to `std::transform`):

```
auto comp = [average](double left, double right)
  { return std::abs(left-average) < std::abs(right-average); };
auto closest = std::min_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), comp);
std::cout << " value closest to average was "
          << *closest << " at position "
          << (closest-std::begin(arr))
          << std::endl;
```

Comment: you missed the second half of the question. Perhaps add something like std::partial_sort with predicate abs(average-i)

Comment: Why use a vector when the number of elements is constant? Use `std::array` instead.

Comment: vector is just fine for examples like this. array is an optimization

Comment: Walter, I don't see it. I mean "and find the number which is closest to it."

Comment: I added that part as a separate answer

Comment: Ha, I added the same version as you just a min ago ;). Exploring the algorithms library is fun.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Fun perhaps, but possibly not helpful and an answer in this context if the solution is outside of the intended course material (very likely).  In an academic assignment the development of algorithms typically is more important (or indeed the sole aim of the exercise) than knowledge of the standard library.

Comment: @Clifford, Exploring the standard library is always helpful. The rest of your comment is right depending on the type of course.

Answer (score 1):

building on to the answer by Walter, adding the 'find value closest to average' part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
  auto average = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),0.0) / arr.size();
  std::cout  << " average = " << average << std::endl;
  auto comp = [average](double left,double right){
     return std::abs(left-average)<std::abs(right-average);  };
  auto mini=std::min_element(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),comp);
  std::cout << "value closest to average was " << *mini <<std::endl;
}
```

Alternative (slower) implementation using transform (reduces the number of calls to fabs, but does a copy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
  auto average = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),0.0) / arr.size();
  std::cout  << " average = " << average << std::endl;
  auto pred=[average](double x){return std::abs(x-average);};
  auto arrcpy = arr;
  std::transform(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),std::begin(arrcpy),pred);
  auto result = std::min_element(std::begin(arrcpy),std::end(arrcpy));
  std::cout << "value closest to average was: " << arr[result-std::begin(arrcpy)];
}
```

Using a standard algorithm is usually the right thing to do as it is more maintainable. In this case I did not find a way to use a standard algorithm as fast as this (about 30% faster than the first solution above with 10e7 elements and -O2):

```
  std::pair<double,double> smallest(std::abs(average-arr[0]),arr[0]);
  for(auto a: arr){
    auto v=std::abs(average-a);
    if(v<smallest.first){
       smallest={v,a};
    }
  }
  std::cout << "value closest to average was " << smallest.second <<std::endl;
```

Comment: okay, now I finally understood the question. Btw, why `std::fabs` rather than `std::abs`?

Comment: *abs is for integers* that is **wrong**, see your C++ manual: `std::abs(double)` is for `double` etc. I think `std::fabs` only exists for backward compatibility to old (`C`-style) code.

Comment: Correct Walter. I used <cstdlib> which does not have std::abs(double), but <cmath> does. Thanks for pointing out that I was *wrong*.